# SQL and VC++ how to automate SQL commands when the tables are being changed?

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-c++, database-design

I am using VC++ and Mysql to build a system that reads and writes data to tables, keeps the data in structs in the memory and sends it to other functions for processing.

During the process of developing an algorithm the Mysql tables are being modified (e.g. more columns are being added).
From the Mysql Workbench a new CREATETABLE commands can be generated for the new tables, however for the process of reading and writing the data from the tables there is a need to manually change the SQL commands within the VC++ each time the tables are being changed.
Are there ways to automate this process? e.g. to get the new SQL commands for reading and writing from the autogenerated CREATETABLE command?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a common practice. Perhaps add more details to further explain the need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, what is not a common practice? that the tables structure is being changes during the development of an algorithm?

Comment: I have not heard of automation.  It might involve (1) mysqldump to get CREATE TABLE, (2) script (Perl?) to convert CREATE to struct to make new .h file.

Comment: It is usually not wise to do only `SELECT *`, which is what your question implies that you are doing.

Comment: Hi Rick, please elaborate a little bit, what is the wise way? I am new to SQL and Mysql. thanks